# Problem with \newcommand

Tags: macros

When I compile the following document, I get the error

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,enumerate}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definição}[section]

\newcommand{\cuatex}[3]
{\begin{center}
\setlength{\unitlength}{2.54cm}
\begin{picture}(#1,#2)
\put(0,0){\framebox(#1,#2){\begin{minipage}{12.5cm}#3\end{minipage}}}
\end{picture}
\end{center}}

\newcommand{\Defi}[2]
{\cuatex{5.2}{#1}{
\begin{defi}
#2
\end{defi}
}}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section 1}
This is only a test.

\Defi{2.1}{Diremos que un conjunto no vacío $X$ es un espacio métrico,
si sobre él está definida una función
$$
d:X\times X
$$
satisfaciendo las siguientes propriedades
\begin{itemize}
\item $d(x,y)=0$ si, y solamente si $x=y$.
\item La función $d$ es simétrica, esto es, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
\item $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ (desigualdad triangular)
\end{itemize}
La función $d$ es llamada métrica.
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But if I want to add  
 \put(0,0){\special{eps:quadrado.eps x=5.2 in y=\yVal in}}
before  
 \put(0,0){\framebox(5.2,\yVal){\usebox\DBox}}
How can I simplify the environment so that "Definição 1.1.1." is inside the box?

Answer (score 5):

Use an environment instead of a command and also `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,enumerate}
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definição}[section]

\newsavebox\DBox
\newenvironment{Defi}[1]
  {\gdef\yVal{#1}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\DBox}
   \minipage{12.5cm}\begin{defi}}
  {\end{defi}   
   \endminipage\end{lrbox}%
   \par\noindent\fbox{\usebox\DBox}}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section 1}
This is only a test.

\begin{Defi}{2.1}
Diremos que un conjunto no vacío $X$ es un espacio métrico,
si sobre él está definida una función
$$
d:X\times X
$$
satisfaciendo las siguientes propriedades
\begin{itemize}
\item $d(x,y)=0$ si, y solamente si $x=y$.
\item La función $d$ es simétrica, esto es, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
\item $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ (desigualdad triangular)
\end{itemize}
La función $d$ es llamada métrica.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Herbert but "Definição 1.1.1." should appear inside the box as in:
http://www.maya-tech.us/images/test.png

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mdframed}

\begin{document}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  innertopmargin=-1ex,
]{defi}{Definição}[section]

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section 1}
This is only a test for stating definition~\ref{defi:metric}

\begin{defi}\label{defi:metric}
Diremos que un conjunto no vacío $X$ es un espacio métrico,
si sobre él está definida una función
\[
d\colon X\times X\to\mathbb{R}
\]
satisfaciendo las siguientes propriedades
\begin{itemize}
\item $d(x,y)=0$ si, y solamente si $x=y$.
\item La función $d$ es simétrica, esto es, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
\item $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ (desigualdad triangular)
\end{itemize}
La función $d$ es llamada métrica.
\end{defi}

Some text below.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `$$...$$` should never be used in LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Thanks @egreg, but when I run it I get:  
! Undefined control sequence.  
l.8 \newmdtheoremenv    
                    [
?

Comment: @LuoKaisa You have an outdated version of `mdframed`; you should update your TeX distribution.

Comment: I did an update to TeXLive 2013 and after running the same tex file I get
![source](http://www.maya-tech.us/images/test5.png)

Comment: @LuoKaisa Strange; remove `innertopmargin=-1ex,`

Comment: I removed it, and it looks fine, but if I change the zoom of the pdf, then some box lines disappear, depending on the zoom rate. For example, with 100% zoom, the horizontal and left lines disappear; with 75% the horizontal line disappear; with 125% the left line disappear... That doesn't happen with the solution from @herbert.